# ListTile not getting updated with Google Places API in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I have this method which gets a suggested place through the Google Places API based on the user input.

```
  void getSuggestion(String input) async {
    var googlePlace = GooglePlace(AppConstants.APIBASE_GOOGLEMAPS_KEY);
    var result = await googlePlace.queryAutocomplete.get(input);
    setState(() {
      _placeList = result!.predictions!;
    });
  }
```

_placeList is filled properly, but it does not get updated instantly, I have to hot reload to see the changes whenever I change the query value in my TextController:

```
TextField(
                        onSubmitted: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            getSuggestion(value);
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: ((context) {
                                  return Card(
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      title: Text(_placeList[0].description),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }));
                          });
                        },
```

For example, if I search for "Miami" I get the recommendation on my listTile, but if I change it to "Madrid" it still appears "Miami" and I have to reload screen to see the change.
I do not understand because I am setting the state in my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSuggestion` is an asynchronous function. In other words, in the following code snippet:

```dart
getSuggestion(value);
showDialog(
  context: context,
  ...
```

After invoking `getSuggestion`, it does not wait the function to finish before showing the dialog. In other words, when the dialog is shown, maybe the previous function hasn't completed yet, so that `_placeList` is not updated yet.

Firstly, it is a better idea to get rid of `setState` within `getSuggestion` as it is redundant to do it twice.

Secondly, in the `onSubmitted` lambda, make the anonymous function async (`onSubmitted: (value) async { ...`), then *wait* for `getSuggestion` to finish by `await getSuggestion()` (do not await inside `setState`). At this point, `_placeList` is updated, and you can invoke `setState` now, things should rebuild properly if there are no other errors.